# CSS slider behaving strangely

Tags: css, slideshow

So I'm learning CSS transitions and transforms and am trying to make a simple slider in CodePen. The basic idea is that I have one div on top of another and I want the first one to slide off the second when hovered on. It works fine without any overflow property, but once I added overflow: hidden to the underlying square, it pushes the overlying square down. Why is this?

http://codepen.io/johnnycopes/pen/BKReOq

--- HTML ---

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape">
    <div class="shape-cover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--- CSS ---

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: #fff0a5;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto
}

.shape {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffb03b;
}

.shape-cover {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #468966;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape-cover:hover {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using a margin on the "overlaying square".

shape-cover is inside the shape, so the margin of the shape-cover will me relative to its parent.

So try removing the margin on the shape-cover div.

Comment: Wow, what a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks!